# Laravel - Display query result for at least one week (query)

Tags: laravel-8, laravel-query-builder, php-carbon

I am using Laravel 8, writing a query, and want to display today's record(Dt.: **17/08/2022**) for at least **one week** which means(***at least for 7 days*** (Dt.: **24/08/2022**)) using carbon.

After one week which means on 25th august records should be excluded from listing.

What should I do to archive this result? any help would be great!

Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It will display any record that is created in the past seven days. that means one week

```
table::where('created_at', '>=', Carbon::now()->subDay(7))->get();
```